# Program gets stuck on reading serial communication of arduino via Pyserial

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

m trying to create a tool that help to simulate key press

but at part of this code mentioned below, the program gets stuck and its not proceeding

```
ser = serial.Serial(ACM)
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.timeout = None
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
ser.write(cmd)
p = ser.readline()
pr = p.decode("utf-8")
print(cmd)
print(pr)
ser.close()
print("Closed")
```

" ser.readline() is not reading the output of serial com /dev/ttyACM*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [PySerial documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline) is unmistakable:

> Be careful when using readline(). Do specify a timeout when opening
> the serial port otherwise it could block forever if no newline
> character is received.

You define: `ser.timeout = None` so what exactly do you expect your program to do, but block forever if you don't receive a newline?

Either make sure the sent lines are terminated or use a reasonable timeout.